# take a get value and make constant variable Django Python

Tags: python, django, request, middleware

I am working in a booking engine project with Django for hotels.
I need when a client selects the hotel, arrival date, and departure date (these parameters are passed with get method) a view takes them, and generates global variables to all views, until the client changes for example the dates.

In each view I need to have the hotel, the arrival date, and departure date. I know that I can do this to template with context processor, but I don't know which is the better way to do this for views.
I was ridding something with middleware, but I don't know.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: you are looking for sessions

Comment: this is the only way?

Comment: read the answer

Answer (score 1):

lets you want to set a var for the current user and use in all views, simply use sessions like this

```
request.session['date'] = your_date
```

then to use this variable in other views you can do this

```
user_date = request.session['date']
```

Comment: Yes i now this way. I thing that may be a way to create a class or something to receipt the values and make them accesibles to all views